# Programmatically resize images uploaded

Tags: 8, media

When uploading images to D8 programmatically the setting for **Maximum image resolution** will be ignored and images will not be scaled down. Some of the images i have to upload are even larger then 10MB.

I am currently using this code.

```
$file_type = explode('.', $image)[1];
$data = file_get_contents($image);
$path = 'public://images/';

if (file_prepare_directory($path, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY)) {

  $file = file_save_data($data, $path . md5($image) . '.' . $file_type, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

  $node = Node::create(array(
    'type' => 'image',
    'title' => $image,
    'field_image' => array(
      'target_id' => $file->id(),
    ),
  ));
  $node->save();

}
```

I've tried to work with `ImageStyle::load('max_2600x2600')`, but that will only create a style in styles directory.

It would be possible to use a custom shell command but i would love to use the Drupal 8 way. How to make sure original images will get resized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Use Image style before save the node.

```
$original_image = 'public://images/image.jpg';

// Load the image style configuration entity.
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;
$style = ImageStyle::load('max_2600x2600');

$uri = $style->buildUri($original_image);
$url = $style->buildUrl($original_image);
```

Here some links may helps you

[Drupal 8 - Create an Image and ImageStyle Programmatically](http://www.gccgeek.com/content/drupal-8-create-image-and-imagestyle-programmatically)

[Drupal 8 images with image style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754661/drupal-8-images-with-image-style)

[Flexible image style system](https://www.drupal.org/node/2050669)

Comment: My image does not come from **public://** but from directory outside of Drupal provided for FTP uploads. You pointed me into the right direction and i've finally managed to resize images while importing them.

Comment: now your issue has been fixed right?

Comment: Yes thanks allot! But the code in your example is not the code that helped me, since it will not create a new image outside of **public://** and i want to create a file with **fid** to attach to the node. I'm using $style->createDerivative($original_image, 'temporary://filename.jpg'); to create a resized image in temporary directory and attach this file to the node and have it imported correctly.

Comment: Nice to here you. Actually this code is how to resize images programmatically using image style. Great job :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing. This code ended up working for me

```
      use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
      use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;
      use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

      $fileName = 'example.jpg';
      $destination =  "public://images/" . $fileName;
      $temporaryFile = 'temporary://' . $fileName;    
      file_save_data($photoData, $temporaryFile, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

      $style = ImageStyle::load('thumbnail');
      $style->createDerivative($temporaryFile, $destination);

      $file = File::create([
        'uid' => 1,
        'filename' => $fileName,
        'uri' => $destination,
        'status' => 1,
      ]);
      $file->save();

      if ($file) {
          $node->get('field_photos')->appendItem([
              'target_id' => $file->id(),
              'alt' => 'Alt text goes here',
          ]);
      }

      ...

      $node->save();
```